# How to add numeric marker in leaflet?

Tags: r, shinydashboard, r-leaflet

How do i add a numeric marker to my leaflet map in my shiny dashboard?
I have this ranking column:
Rank_pop_size
1
2
4
5
3

Is there a way that when i have them marked on a leaflet map instead of a simple point I get the corresponding number in that column as the marker?

Still a bit new to this so thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: See: https://community.rstudio.com/t/numbers-for-markers-in-leaflet-package/821/2